# Store data in list with array from class. C#

Tags: list, arraylist

I cant seem to find the proble, therefore i hope someone out there would be able to guide me to where my mistake is.

```
private List<BoxClass>[] Box = new List<BoxClass>[250];

public class BoxClass
{
        public string amountvalue { get; set; }
        public string amountname { get; set; }
}

private int totalcount = 10;

private void loadvalues()
{
for(int i = 0; i < totalcount; i++)
{
    Box[i].Add(new BoxClass()
    {
        amountvalue = mySqlDataReader["amountvalue"].ToString(),
        amountname = mySqlDataReader["amountname"].ToString(),
    };
}
}
```

Error i get in the debugger in Visual Studio is 
"{System.NullReferenceException: The object reference is not set up to receive an object" <- its translated from danish, since I am using windows in Danish which also gives me the error description in danish also.

There shoudnlt be null bassed or i might misunderstand the error message?

I need to have 250 Box, and in each of the box i need to store amount and values which are coming from a SQL datatable, which works fine if i store everything in a array of strings and load them one by one, but i need them to be stored in list (better than having 6 strings with arrays under each of them)

I thank you all for any help.

Comment: Do the column names `amountvalue` and `amountname` exist in the database?

Comment: Both values exist in the Database, i am able to get the information through  a select statement.

Comment: Please post more code to make enable some more context e.g. where is `mySqlDataReader` initialized and where do you call any methods upon it? Where is `loadvalues()` called from? At which line does the exception occur?

Comment: Hi Some how i got i fixed.

    for (int i = 0; i < 250; i++)
    {
                Box[i] = new List<BoxClass>();
    }

When i declare private List<BoxClass>[] Box = new List<BoxClass>[250]; before InitializeComponent in the top. it some how losses the array somehow, so when i in Loadup add them on each one, might be me that misunderstood something, i get the wanted result 250 boxes of list from my class :) took some trial and error and some looking into casting of list but i managed to figure it out.

Just in case any one was wondering i wrote the working code